# Return the concurrent records that happens at the same time interval

Tags: mysql

I have table like below

```
  id      name      start_time               end_time 

  1       abc       2016-11-01 12:00:00     2016-11-01 12:10:00 
  2       pqr       2016-11-01 12:05:55     2016-11-01 12:15:00 
  3       xyz       2016-11-01 12:05:22     2016-11-01 12:12:33 
  4       lmn       2016-11-01 01:01:22     2016-11-01 01:15:22 
  5       rst       2016-11-01 02:45:11     2016-11-01 02:55:11
```

I have to retrieve the count of students that joined in the same time period.From the above table i have to get the below results

```
id  name    start_time              end_time
1   abc     2016-11-01 12:00:00     2016-11-01 12:10:00
2   pqr     2016-11-01 12:05:55     2016-11-01 12:15:00
3   xyz     2016-11-01 12:05:22     2016-11-01 12:12:33
```

So the count will be three. Here we can see that `id` number `1` joined at `2016-11-01 12:00:00` and he took upto `2016-11-01 12:10:00`.  During the same time period `id` number `2` joined at `2016-11-01 12:05:55` and `3` joined at `2016-11-01 12:05:22`.

Is there any way to get these details in mysql?

I have tried the below query. But it wont give me the exact result. It will retrieve the results only those who have joined at the same time, not in the time period.

```
select count(*) AS num_fog from students  where start_time in (select start_time from students group by start_time having count(*) > 1) ;
```

Comment: May i know how can i use the time period in this case

Comment: Have u read my question clearly?